# How to handle case in React.js hooks when the previous state is in the closure of component's method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component which waits for an API call, sets an empty array as initial state and then on props change it sets the new array.

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 setOptions(optionsFromProps);
}, [optionsFromProps]);
```

The problem is, that I have a function inside of the component which has closure over the first empty array and when I call it, it's being called with empty array event though now options is [{}, {}, {}];

```
// inside of the same component
const foo = () => console.log(options);
// it logs []
// if the initial state would be [1,2,3] then it logs [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Can you paste your whole component, to see if you are again overriding the value to an empty array?

Comment: There is a lot of code and complex logic but I'm sure that the problem is because of closure. I'd set the initial `options` state as `[1, 2, 3]` and has logged it also.

Comment: Did you console inside useEffect to see if it gets inside there? and before render also you can console to see after useEffect if it really sets the right value of options.

Comment: Yep. It does. I can see values from API call rendered before the function `foo` is called.

Comment: We really need to see your other code. Because I can tell you that there is nothing wrong with any of the code you have posted so far. Apart from the fact that having options in state is redundant since you are always updating it anyhow.

Comment: Why does options need to be state?

Answer (score 0):

After an additional discussion over the problem with my colleague, he pointed out that I haven't understood the problem. Basically, the initial question is incorrect and the bug was because in the child component I attached an event listener which had closure over the initial state.

[CodeSundbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/closure-over-initial-state-bug-nzs8w)

So after this, the fix was obvious: on every rerender, the function should be updated, not only on the initial render.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Component = () => {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onMouseDown = () => {
      foo();
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
  }); // fixed
  // }, []); with a bug

  const foo = () => {
    setOptions(options);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOptions([1, 2, 3]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</button>
      <ul>
        {options.map(option => (
          <li>{option}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```